# Minimum number of letters removed, to make a string Peragram

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, programming-challenge, palindrome

Here is the link to the problem [Peragrams](https://open.kattis.com/problems/peragrams).

> **Peragrams**: If a word is an anagram of at least one palindrome, we call it a Peragram.
>
> **Problem**: Given a string, find the minimum number of letters you have to remove from it, so that the string becomes a Peragram.
>
> > Input #1: abc
> >
> > Output #1: 2
> >
> > Input #2: abb
> >
> > Output #2: 0

My Python code is as follows:

```
# Checks whether a string is palindrome
def IsPalindrome(str):
    m = int(len(str) / 2)

    str1 = str[:m]
    str2 = str[m:][::-1]

    if(len(str) % 2 != 0):
        str2 = str[m + 1:][::-1]

    if(str1 != str2):
        return False

    return True

##################################################

str = input()               #Read input from console
toBeRemoved = 0

if(IsPalindrome(str)):      #If the string is already a palindrome
    print(0)
    exit(0)

str = ''.join(sorted(str))  #Sort the string

i = 0
isOdd = True

while i < len(str):
    if(i + 1 < len(str) and str[i] == str[i + 1]):          #If two consecutive chars map, skip matched char
        i += 2
        continue

    toBeRemoved += 1                                        #Increment the number of chars to remove

    if(len(str) % 2 != 0 and isOdd and toBeRemoved > 0):   #If the string is odd length, skip first non-duplicate character & skip to next char
        isOdd = False
        toBeRemoved -= 1
        i += 1
        continue

    str = str[:i] + str[i + 1:] #Remove the char at i

    if(IsPalindrome(str)):
        break

print(toBeRemoved)
```

How can I improve the code to get a better running time?

Comment: Input 2: abb, Output 2: 0. Surely that's not right.

Comment: @mjolka - _abb_ can be written as _bab_ so that 0 chars to be removed to make it palindrome. I think I didn't described the problem clearly.

Comment: Thanks, the link clarifies it. You're not looking for palindromes, but anagrams of palindromes ("peragrams").

Comment: @mjolka - Yes. The code works but isn't efficient.

Answer (score 8):

The approach you are taking is to remove letters until at most one of them has an odd count. Once you realise that, the solution becomes obvious:

```
from collections import Counter

s = input() # don't call your own variable 'str'

c = Counter(s)

odds = [None for n in c.values() if n % 2]

if odds:
    print(len(odds) - 1)
else:
    print(0)
```

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is a `dict` subclass to make counting the letters simpler. You don't actually need to create the substrings or check whether they are peragrams.

---

You should read and consider following [the style guide, PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). For example:

```
if(IsPalindrome(str)):
```

should be:

```
if is_palindrome(s):
```

Comment: Good comment. As an additional comment, you don't need to build the list `odds` as you only care about its length. Also, your final check could be written with `max`. Here is what I got : `print(max(sum(1 for n in Counter(input()).values() if n%2)-1, 0))`.

Comment: @Josay - Python not my native.

Comment: Number of lines of the above code have been drastically reduced which is commendable. But I didn't get any performance enhancement, actually my code ran for 0.0630s and yours ran for 0.0690s. Also, the code written in C/C++ by others ran for less than 0.01s (I don't know the exact times).

Comment: @KunalB. What are you planning to do with the extra 20th of a second?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I may travel 9300m with the speed of light. But that's not the point.

Comment: @KunalB. Your solution becomes slower than the suggested solution when the input becomes bigger. It is easy to see that from a complexity point of view, your solution is at least O(n*log(n)) (because of sorting) while the suggested solution is likely to be 0(n).

Answer (score 2):

I found a palindrome function 4 times faster than yours.

To write it we start with the simplest case: a zero length string is a palindrome:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    if not s:
        return True
```

A string is a palindrome if the first char equals the last and the rest of the string is a palindrome:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    if not s:
        return True
    return s[0] == s[-1] and is_palindrome(s[1:-1])
```

Some timing:

```
import timeit

def IsPalindrome(s):
    m = int(len(s) / 2)

    str1 = s[:m]
    str2 = s[m:][::-1]

    if(len(s) % 2 != 0):
        str2 = s[m + 1:][::-1]

    if(str1 != str2):
        return False

    return True

a = timeit.timeit(lambda: IsPalindrome("ivybft7238789r1b23"))

def is_palindrome(s):
    if not s:
        return True
    return s[0] == s[-1] and is_palindrome(s[1:-1])


b = timeit.timeit(lambda: is_palindrome("ivybft7238789r1b23"))
print(a,b)
```

> 1.9494715500004531 0.5042732839992823